# subversion (SVN) error: can't parse config

Tags: svn

I want to checkout my svn repository on myqnapcloud.com. However, I can only access it through web browser (without any problem) and when I run "svn checkout" then it complains:

> svn: E200002: Error while parsing config file:
>   /etc/subversion/servers:
>
> svn: E200002: line 171: Option expected

I don't know what happens. Would that be a firewall issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Please check if there are leading white spaces in line 171 and remove them.

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your [`servers` runtime configuration file](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.servers) on line 171: `/etc/subversion/servers`. That's why SVN commands do not work.